# Rspec raise_error test failing even though the method raises an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My test looks like this:

`it 'does return an error when passing a non-subscription or trial membership' do
    expect(helper.description_for_subscription(recurring_plan)).to raise_error(RuntimeError)
end`

My method returns this:

`fail 'Unknown subscription model type!'`

Yet Rspec comes back with this failure message:

`Failure/Error: expect(helper.description_for_subscription(recurring_plan)).to raise_error(RuntimeError)
     RuntimeError:
       Unknown subscription model type!`

What is going on??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should wrap the expectation in a block, using `{}` instead of `()`:

```
expect{
  helper.description_for_subscription(recurring_plan)
}.to raise_error(RuntimeError)
```

Check the **Expecting Errors** section [here](https://rspec.info/features/3-12/rspec-expectations/built-in-matchers/)

Comment: The way I think about it is when your are testing a value, such as `expect(a) == b`, you use `()`. When you are testing the result of a transaction, you use a block with `{}`. This is mostly used for testing **raising an error** or **change observation**. Check the documentation I included in the answer